# Animation of CAR using Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-animate, html5-animation

I want to put animation for running car on the road vertically.
As shown in my fiddle, the car animation does work, but I want the car to run on my image on the road and as the car goes farther away, the car should become smaller.

The Html Markup:

```
<div id="b" style="position:absolute;">   
          <img src="http://cliparts.co/cliparts/6Tr/ogp/6Trogpekc.png" style="width:10%"></div>
```

The Jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {          
        //for translate car
        function beeLeft() {
            $("#b").animate({ right: "+=1000" }, 6000, "swing", beeRight);
        }
        function beeRight() {
            $("#b").animate({ left: "+=1000" }, 6000, "swing", beeLeft);
        }

        beeLeft();

    });
```

Link to the fiddle : [example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rxhdnrr5/1/)

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: fiddle works fine for me, car goes horizontal in a loop

Comment: Car run one road path but its not working